# Problem with img path in Linux

Tags: php, html

I am facing an issue while uploading a formatted text/html to the db, things work fine under the WAMP but when doing in LAMP I an having the backslash added to the quotes

```
string(114) "<p>
    <img alt=\"\" src=\"/ckfinder/userfiles/images/aboutkg.jpg\" style=\"width: 607px; height: 221px;\" /></p>
"
```

I am using a Zend_Form and ckeditor. And I am pretty sure I am missing something simple m what is it?

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing PHP's [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) option or its friend [`magic_quotes_runtime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime) . When those are enabled, PHP automatically escapes all quotes that arrive via HTTP request or are retrieved from database and so on. It's a deprecated feature intended to prevent SQL injection. See [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) chapter in PHP manual.

Comment: thanks that was it =), I disabled it from .htaccess "php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off"